# InstaPy BOT for Instagram/ how to run multiple scripts

Tags: python, bots, instapy

I'm using InstaPy to automate my work, but I can't use more than one script at the same time, it works well the first one that I put to run but the second one doesn't. It only executes if I start the script when the first one is finished. Can anyone help me solve this? How do I make the BOT InstaPy run several simultaneously?

this is an example of the InstaPy script, below is the message that appears when executing the second script with information from another account.

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

session = InstaPy(username='username', password='password')

with smart_run(session):
    session.set_do_follow(enabled = True, percentage = 100)
    session.set_do_like(enabled = True, percentage= 100)
    session.follow_user_followers(['user'], amount=30, randomize=False)
    session.set_skip_users(skip_private=True, private_percentage=100, skip_no_profile_pic=True, no_profile_pic_percentage=100)
    comentarios = ['very good','I liked your posts']
    session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=95)
    session.set_comments(comentarios, media= 'Photo')
    session.join_pods()



selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused them
```